simplest way to run a docker container in kubernetes
At my university, we have to use Kubernetes to run jobs on the GPU cluster. I want to train a deep learning model, which is working as a docker container with the following Dockerfile:
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY train.py ./
COPY utils.py ./
COPY models/ ./models
COPY datasets/ ./datasets
COPY install_requirements.sh ./

RUN bash install_requirements.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "train.py"]

What is the simplest way to run this docker container through Kubernetes? All the Kubernetes tutorials I've seen are overkill--I don't need to deploy anything, just execute the python script, which should take a couple of hours, and retrieve the log files it creates.

You'd normally create a Job object.  Almost everything in Kubernetes involves its API layer, and you'll generally be writing a significant Kubernetes manifest in YAML to make it go.

Can you add details on how you access the kubernetes cluster at the moment, which commands are available to you and what you have done already. Also, in general you can always create a minimal viable version locally (as kubernetes can run locally too and then try that on your GPU cluster.)

I access via ssh. The commands available to me include get/create/delete jobs/pods/deployments, not sure of the full list.

@David Maze yes maybe a job is better than a deployment, I'm reading the doc page you linked to but not understanding what the command should be, the command is already in the docker image right? the kubernetes pod just needs to run the container for that image

Then in your Job spec you can omit the command: and args:, and it will run the command out of the specified image:.

ok I see, so I need either ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile that built the image, or command: in the yaml file that I create the Kubernets Job from, but not both

in that case I guess then the simplest is to use controllers/job.yaml in the page you link to, with the command: line removed?

Simple Answer:

Define the deployment:

You need to define a deployment that specifies the Docker container you want to run in your .yaml file.
Replace <your-docker-image> with your Docker image name and <container-port> with the port your container listens on.

Apply changes in the Kubernetes cluster:

Use the kubectl apply command to apply the YAML file to your Kubernetes cluster.

kubectl apply -f <your-yaml-file>.yaml

(Replace <your-yaml-file> with the name of your YAML file. )

(optional) Check everything worked:

check the status of your deployment and the running pods using the following command:

kubectl get deployments
kubectl get pods


Example .yaml file:


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: <your-docker-image>
        ports:
        - containerPort: <container-port>




@David Maze Thanks for the edit, please approve further edits as well.

Thanks, "the port your container listens on"--is this referring to the docker container?

The containerPort: would refer to the port the process inside a long-running server-type container was listening on.  A Job might be more appropriate than a Deployment for something that isn't running a server, and you expect to run to completion and then exit.
